# Apache + mod_fcgid does not spawn/persist processes

Tags: apache-2.2, php7, mod-fcgid

I have apache 2.2 running with mod_fcgid installed, but each request seems to spawn a new process instead of having a pool of workers.
Phpinfo confirms fastcgi is working:

[image]

But no worker processes, a new process is spawned per request:

[image]

The built in server-status handler confirms "Total FastCGI processes: 0".

Am I wrong in understanding what mod_fcgid should provide? I figured just installing the module is enough to have the worker processes spawned automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, the issue was the MPM being used, it looks like prefork isn't compatible. Switching to worker fixed it.